# An employee lying to Store manager

Tags: conflict

I've  been having problems with this one new co-worker. The store manager hired her and she is her friend. This new worker texts or talks to the store manager and lies or twist things that is not all true. For instance I asked her to help me mop the store, she said okay. The other girls also mopped.  She told the store manager that I had her mop the whole store and nobody helped. The store manager confronted me, I said no she didn't mop the whole store. But until this day the store manager believes her over me. What can I  do? I hate liars.

Comment: In the linked question, the employee who is in trouble is a shift manager. In this question, the OP is not a manager. I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @drewbenn: Very different situation.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do much at all because of the relationship between the two of them. Don't get yourself in trouble, when ordering her to do things (do you actually have that authority?) make sure it's with other people around as witnesses and things like that.

Also don't make the mistake of thinking your store manager is stupid and doesn't know the friend is lying, it could be a loyalty issue. The manager could find out the truth in seconds just by asking others, but doesn't want to. This is good information to know.

The same thing applies to family members, quite often their failings are well known to bosses, but they'll sack or discipline someone innocent for pushing the issue, before they'll sack their relative.

Answer (score 1):

This is one for HR.  There is a conflict-of-interest here that is going to affect not only you, but everyone who reports to this manager.

From a website I'm viewing on this, [for more information](https://www.thebalance.com/conflict-of-interest-1918090):

> Conflicts of interest undermine your reputation and integrity if they are allowed. Your coworkers and bosses don't know what to believe. They muddy the water and open you up for criticism, speculation, and doubt.

You'd be best received if you can gather support from your coworkers in going to HR.  If everybody has the same complaint, then the HR folks will know that the problem's really serious.